# CURL request & Response redirecting to Page

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, curl

I would like to ask for your opinion or ideas if you encountered something like this scenario. 
1.) User will send a curl request to http://mycurl_url.com/get_request
2.) get_request function is access through REST API.
3.) get_request function validates any request then redirects them to external site like www.external_site.com/receive_redirect_response_value

for coding here are some sample
Client requesting curl:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://mycurl_url.com/get_request');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
...  // the REST API KEY is submitted here
curl_exec($curl);
```

Then on the mycurl_url.com/get_request here's the code

```
$has_access = has_accessed($_GET['key']);
if ($has_access) {
   header('Location: www.external_site.com/receive_redirect_response_value?value=this_is_the_value');
}

return false;
```

Now the idea here is that the user will do a curl request and if he's allowed then he will be redirected to an external site "PROPERLY". Now I quoted the word "PROPERLY" since based on what I experienced it's redirecting as expected but the problem is upon redirection the "External Site" has no capability of storing any session. It seems like its been in a stateless form just like the first request when we do a CURL RESTFUL API Request.

Can anyone give me an idea on how to achieve a redirection that does not inherit the "Stateless" form upon redirection to the external site?

Hope I was able to make my question clearly. Thanks again

Comment: As far as I know, Sessions cannot be shared across domains.

Comment: What I want to achieve was to use session on the http://mycurl_url.com/get_request but I cannot do that since this is a RESTFUL API request. but the problem is when I redirect to external link even the external link cannot save any session. What I mean is this external site can save session but it seems its functionality of saving the session is gone upon redirection

Comment: Could you update your code to show how/where you are using the session data? Also, how are you attempting to save the session data? I don't see `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE` anywhere in your code.

Comment: The saving of session is on the external site (which I don't have access to). They just informed me that they can't save anything on the session because I'm requesting a restful api through CURL and any redirection happens during that request whether its external I just get a stateless page